# Duplicating a shape in Microsoft Visio n times on the right with a specified horizontal spacing and at the same height

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-visio

Is there any good way to achieve the following?

[image]

Right now I use copy paste and auto-align (or Position > Auto space where I can define the size of the horizontal spacing), which is still a bit tedious. I use Microsoft Visio 2013 Professional on Windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use View > Add-Ons > Visio Extra > Array Shapes:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Copy the orginal shape by pressing control and dragging it to the right position, then hit F4 as often as needed.
There's also an "array shapes" addon in the pro version, that you may use if available.

Comment: Thanks, pressing control and dragging it to the right position does work, but pressing F4 doesn't copy the item :/ (ideally I'd like a way to say copy this 100 times rather than having to click 100 times)